# How to display an item from comboBox to a list Box

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, listbox

I am working on a `window form` application. I have a `comboBox` and a `listBox`. In my comboBox, I have 5 items in it and I want to display the according item that I selected from the comboBox to a listBox.

Let say if I select item 1, it will show item 1. If I select item 2, it will show item 2 and item 1 will disappear and vice versa. So far, I have tried this code

`listBox1.Items.Add(name)`

This ListBox add statment adds the new item to the listBox such as item1, item2, item3 and so on, which is not what I want.

code.

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

           private void loadComboBox()
        {
            myConn = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost; Initial Catalog= dbName; Trusted_Connection = True");

            try
            {
                myConn.Open();
                string query = "select * from Application_Detail";

                myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConn);

                //myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //reading the value from the query
                SqlDataReader dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                //Reading all the value one by one
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    //column is 1 in Application_Detail Data
                    string name = dr.GetString(1);
                    applicationComboBox.Items.Add(name);
                }
                myConn.Close();
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void fill_checkListBox()
        {
            myConn = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost; Initial Catalog= dbName; Trusted_Connection = True");

            try
            {
                myConn.Open();

                int index = applicationComboBox.SelectedIndex + 1;
                string query = " SELECT td.chineseName, ad.applicationId, aud.applicationId, ad.applicationName FROM[AppUser_Detail] as aud LEFT OUTER JOIN[Teacher_Detail] as td ON aud.teacherId = td.teacherId LEFT OUTER JOIN[Application_Detail] as ad ON aud.applicationId = ad.applicationId LEFT OUTER JOIN[Class_Detail] as cd ON aud.classId = cd.classId where aud.applicationId = '" + index + "' AND NOT(td.teacherId IS NULL AND cd.classId IS NULL)";
                myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConn);

                SqlDataReader dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                //Reading all the value one by one
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    //column is 1 in Application_Detail Data



                        //string value = applicationComboBox.GetItemText(applicationComboBox.Items[i]);
                        string name = dr.GetString(0);
```

teacherCheckListBox.Items.Clear();\ updated this line                           teacherCheckListBox.Items.Add(name);

```
                }
                //teacherCheckListBox.DataSource = dt;
                myConn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you want your list box to show only one item at a time, which was selected from combobox? and combobox will have 4 items max, as 1 will be  moved to listbox?

Comment: Yeah something like that. You know that most of the comboBox in the pc? It only show the item what you selected from the comboBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to clear the listbox and insert only one item.

```
private void cmbSample_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstSample.Items.Clear();
    lstSample.Items.Add(cmbSample.SelectedItem);
    lstSample.SelectedItem = cmbSample.SelectedItem;
}
```

However here `lstSample.Items.Clear();` clears whatever was in the listbox. And if you don't want that, then you can avoid this line and continue with rest two lines which will insert a new item in existing listbox and will select the newly added item.

```
private void cmbSample_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstSample.Items.Add(cmbSample.SelectedItem);
    lstSample.SelectedItem = cmbSample.SelectedItem;
}
```

Comment: hey amnesh, a different situation now. What If I binded to sql data server and have something like `while(sqlReader.Read()){ string name sqlReader.GetString(0); comboCheckListBox.Items.Add(name); }` the `GetString(0)` say that I have a data base table where I want to get the string at column 0 (1st column) and display the text. Its there a way I can do it? It is because as you can see, the checked listbox add a name everything I slected a comboBox item.

Comment: I amk not sure if it make sense

Comment: @DragonBorn it doesn't make much sense to me.. u need to be little more clear

Comment: Hi  Amnesh, I have updated my code. right now everytime I clicked my comboBox, it add a name to a checked listbox. So if I select item 1 from comboBox it display name1. If I select item2 at comboBox, it display name1 and name2. If I select item3, it display name1, name2, name3. If I go back and select item1 again, it display name1, name2, name3, name1. This is not what I want.

Comment: What I want is If I select item1 from comboBox, it display name1. If I select item2 from comboBox, it display name2. If I select item3, it display name3. If I select item1, it will display only item 1 again. I can't get this work. Does it make more sense now? :)

Comment: I did the teacherCheckListBox.text = name; and when I displaying it to the messageBox, it work, but cannot show to value in the check listBox

Comment: @DragonBorn why don't you use `lstSample.Items.Clear();` then.. this will clear the existing list from listbox..

Comment: Hi Amnesh, I have tried, but this just cleared my entire things. Also if I put item.clear first, it only display one item and if there are two item, the first item clear out. I have updated what i have tried. It works if you only have one item, but if you need to disply more than two items, than it doesnt work

Comment: @DragonBorn what is your actual use case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90140/discussion-between-amnesh-goel-and-dragonborn).

Answer (score 2):

```
   public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<string> items = new List<string>();
            items.Add("sachin");
            items.Add("dravid");
            items.Add("ganguly");
            cmbSample.DataSource = items;
        }

        private void cmbSample_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lstSample.Items.Clear();
            lstSample.Items.Add(cmbSample.SelectedItem);
            lstSample.SelectedItem = cmbSample.SelectedItem;
        }
```

Comment: @DragonBorn ... Then in that case, you don't need to clear the list.. Remove the line `lstSample.Items.Clear();` and remaining code will add new item every time.